# cake php calling a function, but the controller wont execute it

Tags: php, cakephp

i'm from codeIgniter , but for an internship I have to debug an ongoing website using cakePHP.

I'm familiar with mvc but currently stuck and unable to find any solution even after searching.

What I want is to be able to call a function in a controller  (easy task with codeIgniter) ,but during the debug I noticed that the controller was called, but not the function:

```
    <?php
 App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
class FournisseursController extends AppController { //debug stop here
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');    
    public function index() {
        $this->set('Personnes', $this->Fournisseur->find('all'));
    }     

    public function addFournisseur() {
        //contain some code , but not usefull for this problem
        }
    }
}
?>
```

after the 2 first line , the associated view is displayed (it's a weird concept to always have a view displayed, but I guess cake php work this way).
and debug dont even start on the targeted function.

I call it from a view:

```
<form action="../../Fournisseurs/addFournisseur" method="post">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I know it's not really good to call a controller from view , but in that case I need the user to enter some data to send it in a database, I dont know any other way.
I already read the doc concerning controller and it didnt help.

One last thing , if I change the name of the function in the controller , the controller will not be called : an error message explain the the method dont exist (so for me the controller know I want to call the function, because the controller need it to run).

it's been a day since i'm stuck on this and i'm pretty sure it's a stupid mistake.
thanks for reading this even if you dont answer , and sorry if I made any english mistake, it's my first post and i'm not a native speaker.

Comment: try making that function static: `public static function addFournisseur`

Comment: So instead of the method being invoked, what actually happens exactly?

Comment: addFournisseur is an action of your controller, there is nothing fancy about that ; you could call it with ajax, and render the addFournisseur view in a Ajax template, so that your page won't be refreshed entirely. About your debugging problem, have you tried using the cakephp 'debug($data)' function in the addFournisseur function?

Comment: To be clear, you think that having a form with an action in your view means that the corresponding action is going to be executed at the time that you are generating the form?

Comment: @Marcin just tryed , it didnt work.

Comment: @proprit I didnt know about debug($data) function , (for me Xdebug was enough) but now i can see that the function is actually executed, thanks a lot this will help !

Answer (score 0):

I was only relying on Xdebug ,despite the breakpoint it was not stopping in the function ,so I thought it was not called (the function and the code inside it), but with the help of the  `debug($data)` function the breakpoint worked and I was able to keep debuging in the function.

I dont know why Xdebug acted this way ,but I will not rely only on it now.

thanks to everyone who helped, I can keep going now!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Form helper like below, where you can define the contoller and action name:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Fournisseur', array('url' => array('controller' => 'Fournisseurs', 'action' => 'addFournisseur'))); ?>
// Form elements
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```